# intuition behind parameter estimation in CFA

Tags: self-study, confirmatory-factor

I've understood, that the computation of factor loadings L in confirmatory factor analysis can be done by minimising the distance between a variance-covariance matrix A (which results from applying L) with a variance-covariance matrix B, which results from the observed data.

However, when a "distance", i.e. a single number, between A and B is applied and L is a vector, we are in an optimisation problem, which is N:1, where N is the length of L as well as the number of inputs to the objective function and 1 is the dimensionality of the output of the objective function. This leaves, generally speaking, freedom for several solutions or different L fulfilling the optimality condition. I wonder why there is a unique solution to this procedure. Why can (seemingly several, but for instance maximum likelihood) methods find a unique solution for L?

Any hint to an open textbook with a proof? Any intuitive idea, why L should be unique in CFA seen as optimisation problem?

Answer (score 0):

If we focus the question on maximum likelihood parameter estimation for CFA, we not only seek for the minimum distance between two variance-cocarince-matrices, but also for resulting variances, which make the observations/data most probable. In terms of an optimisation problem, this creates side conditions and will lead to preferring some of the solutions for L, which would ideed be infinitely many without this "most probability"-creating side conditions.